# WordPress sidebar: appear only on certain pages

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

How can I edit the php to get my WordPress sidebar to only appear on select pages (i.e. not on the home and about pages)?

I'd prefer php over css if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [is_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page) in your template and rendering the sidebar only if you need to.

Small example, in `sidebar.php` of the twentyten theme of WordPress

```
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <ul class="xoxo">
            <?php 
             if (is_page('my-page')) { 
                  dynamic_sidebar( 'secondary-widget-area' ); }
            ?>
        </ul>
</div><!-- #secondary .widget-area -->
```

This little snippet outputs the sidebar only if you are in the page that has the slug 'my-page'.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4):

You could create a page template that doesn't include the call to `get_sidebar()`, then just use that template for whichever pages you don't want your sidebar appearing on.